# Why is the weak operator closure of a commutative $\boldsymbol{C^*\!\!\!\!-}$algebra also commutative?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In a book on Operator Theory there is the following statement:

*If $\mathscr A$ is a commutative $C^*$-subalgebra of $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, where $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space, then the weak operator closure of $\mathscr A$ is also commutative.*

I can not prove this. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: See Murphy's book on C* algebras, the chapter on von Neumann algebras. Btw you should vote and accept answers you got to encourage people answer your questions

Comment: Take limits and use continuity of multiplication in each variable separately.

Comment: thanks for your help. your are right but i dont know how can i vote to the answers. i need your guidance.

Comment: @joker Click the up arrow near each answer that is helpful. You can also click the checkmark on the answer you think is best. This rewards those answerers with reputation points.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, $A_n\to A$ weakly iff
$$
(u,A_nv)\to(u,Av), \quad \text{for all $u,v\in H$}.
$$
Assume that $A,B$ belong to the weak closure of the commutative sub-algebra $\mathscr A$,
and $A_n\to A$, $B_n\to B$, weakly, with 
$\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N},\{B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\mathscr A$. Then $A_nB_m=B_nA_m$, for all $m,n\in\mathbb N$. Fix know $u,v\in H$. Then, as $n\to \infty$, we have that
$$
(u,A_n B_m v)\to (u,A B_m v)
$$
and
$$
(u,A_n B_m v)= (u,B_mA_nv)=(B_m^*u,A_nv)\to (B_m^*u,Av)=(u,B_mAv)
$$
and hence $(u,A B_m v)=(u, B_mA v)$, for all $u,v\in H$, and hence $AB_m=B_mA$, for all $m\in\mathbb N$. Repeating this for $(u,A B_m v)=(u, B_mA v)$, and letting $m\to\infty$, 
we obtain that $(u,A B v)=(u, BA v)$, and hence $AB=BA$.

Comment: Does there always exist a **sequence** (as opposed to a net) converging to every element of the weak closure? At least if the underlying set is not an algebra, this is false, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666837/convergence-in-the-strong-weak-operator-topology-nets-versus-sequences.

Comment: I am afraid that the question you cite is not relevant.

Comment: The question I cite shows that in general, the closure of a set w.r.t. the weak topology on the space of bounded operators is **not** given by the "sequential closure" of the set (doesn't it?) And your proof only uses sequences (although writing everything in terms of nets would be trivial).